# OData - Checking if the result has entries before returning it

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, odata

how can I check if the result has entries after the filter?
I call the link like

https://localhost:44323/Test?$filter=Id eq '1234567' and Month eq 2 and Year eq 2024

and I get

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44323/$metadata#Test",
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": "1234567",
            "Year": 2024,
            "Month": 2,
            "Money": 2621533.00
        }
    ]
}
```

When there is no entry found, I get

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44323/$metadata#Test",
    "value": []
}
```

But I want to return a dummy entry, if nothing is found.
How can I check, if there value is empty like this?

I'm trying to find something in the Get like:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Test> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Test> queryOptions){
    
     if(db.Test == null){
        Test dummy = new Test();
        Test.Id = 1337;
        ...
        db.Test.Attach(dummy);
     }
     return db.Test;
}
```

Comment: Remove [EnableQuery], use queryOptions to call ApplyTo()...
Then, test the result, if it's empty, create a collection containing the dummy item.
otherwise, return the result.

Comment: Yes, I went for my own Get, without the EnableQuery. Thanks.